# I can't find the "stamp" block in Scratch 3

Tags: mit-scratch

I can't find the "stamp" block in Scratch 3. Can't also find most of the blocks with the pen symbol

Comment: JJJ, wrong answer, sorry.

Comment: @RuudHelderman Thanks a lot...highly appreciated, however, my worry is that just flagging/removing JJJ's comment is not enough, he'll do the same elsewhere...I hope SO comes up with sterner ways to deal with such users for the collective good and longevity of the platform.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pen blocks ('stamp' is one of those) are a separate extension in Scratch 3.0.
Please follow these steps to access these blocks.

- Open your project ('look inside').
- Click on the 'Add Extension' button at the far bottom left of the window.
- Select 'pen'.

You should now see 'Pen' as a separate category in the toolbar along the left-hand side of your window.
Within that category, 'Stamp' is the second block from the top.

You only need to do this once per project.

During the migration from Scratch 2.0 to Scratch 3.0 (January 2, 2019), the pen extension was automatically added to every existing project on the Scratch website that contained pen blocks. So no need to add the extension yourself there.

See also:

- https://en.scratch-wiki.info/wiki/Pen_Extension

Answer (score 2):

The Scratch Team made the pen category an **extension**. To get the stamp block and the rest of the pen blocks, you need to click the **bottom left of the screen** where it has **2 Scratch blocks and a plus symbol**. Then click "**Pen**".

Answer (score 2):

It is now an extension. So, now you have to go to "Add Extensions" and click "Pen". Then, the "Pen" menu is out.